# Use nodemailer with Gmail password

Tags: node.js, authentication, security, nodemailer

hi guys I'm asking whether I can use nodemailer with my gmail passowrd not the application password.
since whenever I tryed to do so I get this error :

```
Error in sending email: Error: Invalid login: 534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at
```

534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor h5-20020a170906718500b009ddf38056f8sm8150481ejk.118 - gsmtp

Answer (score 0):

- Google

  [Sign in with app passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?visit_id=638357553672512768-3126364917&p=InvalidSecondFactor&rd=1)
- nodemailer

  [Using Gmail](https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/)
- stackoverflow

  [Nodemailer and Gmail after May 30 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71477637/nodemailer-and-gmail-after-may-30-2022/72477193#72477193)

**index.js**

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: process.env.MAIL_SERVICE,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.MAIL_USERNAME,
    pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD,
  },
});

const mailOptions = {
  from: process.env.MAIL_USERNAME,
  to: process.env.MAIL_USERNAME,
  subject: req.body.subject,
  text: req.body.text,
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(info);
  }
});
```

**environment.env**

```
MAIL_SERVICE='gmail'
MAIL_USERNAME='stackoverflow@gmail.com'
MAIL_PASSWORD='stackoverflow@gmail.com'
```